# Polymer 1.x : get/return property values for no related elements

Tags: javascript, polymer

Question for Polymer users:

How I can get property value, if elements are not parent-child or child-parent related? As I understand chain of listeners is really bad idea. Is it possible to specify concrete element to listen for event?

I know that it can be done JS way:

```
document.addEventListener('event', handle('elem'));
```

But I need Polymer way.

Thank you.

Comment: What does your `handle('elem')` return?

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's designed that way.

> Isolated DOM: A component's DOM is self-contained (e.g.
>   document.querySelector() won't return nodes in the component's shadow
>   DOM).

Ref. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

You should rely on data binding and events to communicate between web components built on shadow DOM. And, Polymer elements are such web components.

Comment: Since @laurynas removed querySelector from his question after my answer, I'd assume the problem was something else.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Polymer uses the mediator pattern, which means a parent mediates all its children and, as such, only the parent can access the children's properties using bindings.

Two-way bindings are [implemented using events](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding), i.e., instead of a two-way binding, you can also do:

`<child-element property-changed="onPropertyChanged_"></child-element>`

However, since these events are non-bubbling, you can access it only in the parent component.

If you want a more global state management and share certain state across your application, you should take a look at [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), potentially in combination with the Polymer bindings [Polymer-Redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux). See [Kevin's this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A-2BhEZiM4) with more information on this topic.